# grep multiple input

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have multiple directory

```
home/user/test_a/test_a.gz
home/user/test_b/test_b.gz
home/user/test_c/test_c.gz
...
```

I want to run `zgrep "word" home/user/test_a/test_a.gz > result` on all the other .gz files and output to the same file automatically.
(Assuming there's only 3 folders under home/user/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 find path -type f -iname "*.gz" -exec zgrep  "word" {} \; >>result
```

Tested and worked fine